# Kendo UI Filters at backend?

Tags: php, kendo-ui

So I'm trying to do an autocomplete using this framework - Kendo.

[image]

Question is how do I read this data on server side? Like let's say I'm using PHP. How do I get this data?
And how Do I pass a value to the server side?

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is to make an ajax post call. Good option would be to use jquery.

First store your data from kendo:

```
var data_from_kendo = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid")
```

Then send it over to your php with jquery post:

```
$.post( "yourphp.php", {data_from_kendo: data_from_kendo}, function(response_from_php) {
    console.log(response_from_php)
})
```